# Как правильно отобразить Dialog?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядит в  AS макет диалога.

А вот так он отображается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вся беда в том что Dialog распознает родительскую разметку XML как WRAP_PARENT

Хотя должен как MATCH_PARENT

Что сделать?

Comment: Не пользоваться предпросмоторщиком.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет это из эмулятора), нашел выход указанием 240dp. Но разве это правильно?

на больших экранах отступ слишком большой по краям.

Есть другой способ?